# How to get keyevent to work in an applet?

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener, keyevent

I've looked around a bit and I can't seem to find the answer to my problem... As far as I can tell, this should work fine but I'm clearly missing something.

I have this bit of code which should print something to the console both when I press and when I release the enter key but that doesn't appear to work. Could someone possibly help me out please? Thanks!

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class test extends Applet implements Runnable {

public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void start() {
    setSize(500, 500);
}

public void run() {

}   

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        System.out.println("You are pressing ENTER!");
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        System.out.println("You are releasing ENTER!");
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1):

Have your class test implement java.awt.event.KeyListener, this way it can be used to monitor your keyboard.  All you have to do is invoke addKeyListener(this) in your test class.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped and it fixed my issue. I added addKeyListener(this) into my start() and it now prints when I press enter. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run method is empty!? you must have some content there to be able to get the events. Right now your applet starts and run() is invoked but runs out and the thread ends. Test if this is the case by adding

```
run(){
    while(true){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

or something

Comment: You need to add `KeyListener` to the Applet.